# Convert 5v 20mA to 12v 0.4Amps

Tags: power-supply, power, converter, 3d, printed

I am going to be making a 3d printer and i have made a circuit to control it. However, the stepper motor is 12v 0.4amps and the circuit is 5v 20mA. I need a way to amplify, but if you can show me, please give me the fritzing file, not something like eagle or PDF. This is because i am making the circuit with fritzing.

Comment: It's compiling as we speak...

Comment: You can't get 4.8W (12V*0.4A) out of 0.1W (5V*0.02A). You need to use the 5V signal to control the stepper, but you need a separate power supply to power the stepper.

Comment: Gave an ee.PowerExceeded error!

Comment: Pro's don't use Fritzing.

Comment: What do you mean by "the circuit is 5V 20mA"? Where did you find these numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, first thing you must know: you cannot get power out of nowhere. Power is voltage times current, so if your input P is 5*0.02=0.1W, then your output P will not be more than that, whatever you do.

So tell us more about what you have, maybe we come help better than "it's impossible"